# I want to create hamburger menu which will be at bottom right, react navigation, I'm using createMaterialBottomTabNavigator no success

Tags: react-native, material-design, react-navigation

MaterialBottomTabNavigator do not accept any button, until I set a route to it. I want a menu that pops up from bottom right position when i click that specific button in material bottom tab navigation

Answer (score 0):

hamza do the steps below:

first install

> yarn add react-navigation-tabs

or use npm

> npm install react-navigation-tabs

on your navigator file .js add this

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { Icon} from 'react-native-elements';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {

 //choose the screen page you want and add the option like default options and colors

            home: {
                screen: ItemsNavigator,
                navigationOptions: {

 //for icon you must use the icon set you install here i use icon from react-native-elements, just use your own , material or etc

                    tabBarIcon: (tabInfo) => {
                        return <Icon reverse name="ios-home" type="ionicon" size={25} color={tabInfo.tintColor} />;
                }
            }
        }

    },
    {
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: 'tomato',
            inactiveTintColor: 'gray'
        }
    }
)


 //final step is make your app container , pass your constant name or top level navigator


export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator );
```